# iOS Archive Fails: Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

I am trying to archive my iOS project and it is failing on the ditto command, after it has compiled every file, supposedly.

The entire logfile is ~200MB with sensitive information, so I will not post it.
This is the failing line of output.

```
Ditto /Users/iosjenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dikjbbwmnvizjmdpbkrxixczfmqo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Development-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/MyApp-Swift.h /Users/iosjenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dikjbbwmnvizjmdpbkrxixczfmqo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Development-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp-Swift.h
cd /Users/iosjenkins/.jenkins/jobs/MyAppDevelopmentNightly/workspace/MyApp
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode7.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/iosjenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dikjbbwmnvizjmdpbkrxixczfmqo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Development-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp-Swift.h /Users/iosjenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dikjbbwmnvizjmdpbkrxixczfmqo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Development-iphoneos/MyApp.build/DerivedSources/MyApp-Swift.h
ditto: can't get real path for source '/Users/iosjenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dikjbbwmnvizjmdpbkrxixczfmqo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Development-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp-Swift.h'
Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

My project is very large ~ 1000 swift files. Each line of output of the xcodebuild compilation is 110k characters of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed with recent versions of Xcode as of version 8.

Answer (score 3):

In case others still get this problem, I had this error after not revisiting a project for a while. It went away after a Clean:

Command-Shift K

or

Product > Clean

Answer (score 1):

This might be an XCode 7.2 issue:
http://codica.pl/2015/12/25/taming-swift-compiler-bugs/

Comment: @PaoloMusolino am also facing the same issue with Xcode 9.2. did you manage to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Clean
2. Quit Xcode
3. Open Finder then go to  **~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData** then
   deleate everything inside this folder
4. Open Xcode
5. Build

By the way this issue happened to me after I ran 'CleanMyMac' which what it seems like removed part of the DerivedData.

Answer (score 0):

For me, ***changing the path of derived data*** helped.

Before that, I tried to clean (cmd+shift+k), delete derived data, tried pod update, restart xcode, etc. but nothing seemed to work.